# How to Learn Doing it Right Way?

Tags: efficiency

I am self taught web developer. I do not have any computer science degree from university. I know HTML5, CSS3, Javascript, PHP and some Python. But I am having difficulties about being efficient. When I create a project, I am buried into files, folders, bugs and todoes. Because I am managing multiple projects at a time, I totally feel stressed and not in control.

I see real programmers whom have computer science degrees use utilities like Git for source management. They use Unit tests for testing and other tools for Debugging in an easy and quick way. I am sure there are lots of other tools they have which help them stay safe and calm while they manage their projects.

But because I do not have any computer science degree, I do not know how to do things in a right and efficient way. I just do it, in an organized way. It works but it burns out me, too.

I Googled a bit and find some books from Amazon about Project Management but I feel intimidated. The tools and resources I found also very scattered which seems getting them together to create an organized routine is also requires another expertise.

As a self taught web developer what can I do to learn doing things right way? Do I need a computer science degree or a course about programming? Can I learn the right way by Googleing or from books?

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6488/40980

Comment: **The single best way to learn something is to actually do it.** You will make mistakes, and run against walls a time or two. That's ok, it's called "learning". Join sites like SO, newsgroups etc. where experienced people hang around, to learn from them. Pick one thing (e.g. Git), grab a web tutorial and start playing around. Then start using it in your daily work. Ask questions in the groups you joined. Look for other resources (web,mags,books). Once you get some knowledge, start *answering* questions. Read the comments you get, and improve.

Then pick the next thing and start over.

Answer (score 4):

A compSci degree will not teach you how to organise your work, or how to use tools like git.

Go for source control basics to better manage your projects, once you've learned how to use them, yu might find yourself less stressed because you'll know your code is more secure.

Then just do less, 1 thing at a time works well - finish it before staring on the next, even if that "thing" is just a discrete task for one project. Try a project tracking/bug tracking system (eg redmine) to help you keep track of what you're doing, what you have left to do, and what you have done.

Comment: +1(00000) for computer science degree not teaching you to be a developer, it will only prepare you to learn to be a good developer.